# How ot get items from minicart.js in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on **minicart.js**. I want to get the itmes of minicat in php but unable 
to do so. 
minicart.js have builtin function **paypal.minicart.cart.items()** which return the arrays of items. How to get array of items in php so I can save these items to database and further use.

`<script>
   paypal.minicart.cart.items().forEach(
   console.log.bind(console));
</script>`

Comment: Could you add some code, and show us what you tried ?

Comment: Please add code you've tried.

Comment: https://github.com/jeffharrell/minicart is the minicart.js  which i am using. Basically I want the output of builtin java script function paypal.minicart.cart.items() in php. I am searching this for 2 days.

Comment: you need to get the output of that function into a variable, and then send it in to the server either via form postback (you'd have to put it in a hidden field first) or perhaps it would be better via ajax. If you don't know how to do either of those things, take a tutorial in the relevant subject, there are hundreds available.

Answer (score 2):

first thing you need to change "action:" in minicart.js from paypal link to post.php
make file post.php
type this code inside it

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
```

Comment: How does solve the problem presented in the question?

Comment: Can you enhance your solution? Its not clear if the post.php should be a new file or not.